# reloadSections:withRowAnimation: doesn't update number of rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a `UITableView` in widget and I wish to reload it with an animation. `[self.tableView reloadData]` works great, yet the reloading is not animated. I know I should use `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` for animating, yet there's a problem.

The table is indeed being updated, and `numberOfRowsInSection:` returns the new value, yet the visually the number of rows seen is still the same.

**For instance:** if I had a `UITableView` with 2 rows and I want to update it to 4 rows, there will be still 2 rows in the table. What is inside those 2 cells will be updated as expected, but there should be 4 cells. and I know `numberOfRowsInSection:` returns 4.

This problem doesn't occur when calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` instead of `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`

The workaround I found was this short snippet:

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Calling the two methods one after the other reloads the table with animation and with the 4 cells. I assume this is an iOS 8 bug, perhaps because I use the tableView in a widget?

Comment: You should be using 
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: not reloadSections:withRowAnimation

Comment: @rdelmar Why should I use this method when I want to reload the entire section and add new rows?

Comment: I looked into this some more, and reloadSections should work ok (it does for me in iOS 8). You need to show more code; specifically, how you're updating your data source and where you're calling reloadSections.

Comment: @rdelmar After further investigation, it seems that after calling reloadSection the contentSize value wasn't updated in time, so the widget was still the old size. anyway I found how to fix this. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question but for the sake of reference. `reloadSections: withRowAnimation:` only reloads currently visible cells. You should instead use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:` to add the two additional rows that you would like.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections:withRowAnimation:) seem a bit sparse (ambiguous?) on this information but they do say:

> Calling this method causes the table view to ask its data source for new cells for the specified sections.

Does not explicitly state that it will ask for a new row count, and as you see in the behavior you are experiencing, this happens to be true.